# Position frequency matrix for Pandas column with strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, position, frequency

I have a pandas Dataframe with a column of peptide sequences and I want to know how many times each each amino acid appears at each position. I have written the following code to create the position frequency matrix:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

def frequency_matrix(df):
    # Empty position frequency matrix
    freq_matrix_df = pd.DataFrame(
        columns =  sorted(set(chain.from_iterable(df.peptide_alpha))),
        index=range(df.peptide_len.max()),
    ).fillna(0)

    for _, row in df.iterrows():
      for idx, aa in enumerate(row["peptide_alpha"]):
        freq_matrix_df.loc[idx, aa] += 1
    
    return freq_matrix_df
```

which for the following sample DataFrame:

```
mini_df = pd.DataFrame(["YTEGDALDALGLKRY", 
                        "LTEIYGERLYETSY",
                        "PVEEFNELLSKY", 
                        "TVDIQNPDITSSRY", 
                        "ASDKETYELRY"], 
                       columns=["peptide_alpha"])
mini_df["peptide_len"] = mini_df["peptide_alpha"].str.len()
```

|  | peptide_alpha | peptide_len |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | YTEGDALDALGLKRY | 15 |
| 1 | LTEIYGERLYETSY | 14 |
| 2 | PVEEFNELLSKY | 12 |
| 3 | TVDIQNPDITSSRY | 14 |
| 4 | ASDKETYELRY | 11 |

gives the following output:

|  | A | D | E | F | G | I | K | L | N | P | Q | R | S | T | V | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 10 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 11 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 14 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

This works for small DataFrames but because of the for loop becomes too slow for bigger datasets. Is there a way to rewrite this in a faster/vectorized way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

```
mini_df['peptide_len'] = mini_df.peptide_len.map(lambda x: range(x))
mini_df['peptide_alpha'] = mini_df.peptide_alpha.map(list)
mini_df = mini_df.explode(["peptide_alpha", "peptide_len"])

pd.crosstab(mini_df.peptide_len, mini_df.peptide_alpha)
```

**Performance**

With the dataframe

```
mini_df = pd.concat([mini_df] * 10000)
```

On my machine, my solution solves the problem within `0.5s`, whereas the solution of the OP takes `1m8.6s`. Consequently, I believe that my solution can be useful for him.

**Output**

```
peptide_alpha  A  D  E  F  G  I  K  L  N  P  Q  R  S  T  V  Y
peptide_len                                                  
0              1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  1
1              0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  2  2  0
2              0  2  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
3              0  0  1  0  1  2  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
4              0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1
5              1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
6              0  0  2  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1
7              0  2  1  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
8              1  0  0  0  0  1  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
9              0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1
10             0  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1
11             0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1
12             0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0
13             0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  2
14             0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```